# Safari doesn't make a div 100% of it's parent's height

Tags: html, css, safari, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a website, where the structure of a section is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <section class="right" data-type="background" data-speed="30" style="background: url(<?php echo get_field('book_image')['url']; ?>);">
    </section>
</div>
```

The parent div in this situation has (in safari) a height 2976px. However, the child won't size itself to the same height, even though I've applied the `height` property to it.

I tried this in Chrome & Safari, both on macOS: Chrome worked, Safari didn't.

Is there any was to get this to work, preferably without any JS? Thanks :)

-- Edit

I'm using Bootstrap4, however, the `right` class only contains properties to style the div. Contents below

```
  .right {
    max-width: 50vw;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 60vh !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

-- Edit #2.

Here's a snippet demonstrating the problem:

```css
.left {
  padding: 0;
  background: #000; /*debugging*/
  height: 200px; /*debugging*/
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 60vh !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <section class="right" data-type="background" data-speed="30" style="background: red;"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(or in JSFiddle: [Click me](https://jsfiddle.net/rr8yvf5r/3/)

Comment: Do you use bootstrap or other solution, if you have css which consider to your class="right" pleadse tell me

Comment: `height:100%;` of child, `inline-block` parent

Comment: @Levon Edited my post :)

Comment: @Hash This doesn't yield any results at my end

Comment: Would you mind sharing a short pen/fiddle? At least we'd need to know how your CSS looks, especially for the parental `col-md-6` div.

Comment: vw   support from safari 10.1 and 11 . Maybe this is your problem ?

Comment: @Aer0 I've added a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

As an advice  you can use webpage [CANIUSE](http://www.caniuse.com)
,you can check which css property does browser support . In my opnion the best solution  is to use **jquery** or **javascript** to set height of div , when page will be resize or will be load. **You can't find absolute perfect solution to solve  crossbrowser support** . If you need help with jquery  do not hesitate ask when you need .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your parent `div` doesn't have an height property. Even though Chrome is able to resolve the containers height, Safari (and maybe some other browsers) isn't. In order to fix this you've to specify a height for the 2nd `div` in your `.row` (the parent of `.right`) as well.

Styling

```
.right-parent {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Markup

```
<div class="col-6 right-parent">
  <section class="right" data-type="background" data-speed="30" style="background: red;"></section>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rr8yvf5r/4/)

Comment: Good solution , but how will you solve problems which comes from fixed height , in responsive situation , THANK YOU.

Comment: Set a percentage based height. Just keep in mind doing so you need to start either from the root container (html, body) or within a container with an absolute height (like 200px in my example).